# Why is share button missing in my facebook generated page-plugin iframe ?

Tags: facebook, share

Facebook code for page share iframe can be generated here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

In example for "https://www.facebook.com/facebook" there is "share" but when i try some other link like for example "https://www.facebook.com/stranasas" share button is replaced with "contact us" and when i try my page share button is replaced with "More info".

How can this be set, i want to have "share button", its code property of iframe or it depends on some setting in facebook page itself ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what CtA you have set up in the page settings.

On your page, below the cover picture, you should see either "+ Add a Button", or the one you previously configured (if any.)

If you want a specific CtA button to be shown on your page header as well as in the page plugin, configure it there.